# Is /var/lib/dpkg/arch missing from some OSes causing /etc/cron.daily/dpkg to do excess SD card writes?

Tags: cron, raspbian, dpkg

/etc/cron.daily/dpkg causes SD card updates every day in /var/backups (seen on Rasp PI Stretch Lite) even if there are no package changes. I think it is looking for /var/lib/dpkg/arch which does not exist.

Would adding this /etc/cron.daily/dpkg line fix the problem?

```
dbfiles="arch status diversions statoverride"
for db in $dbfiles ; do
    [ -e $dbdir/$db ] || continue      <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Or, is there a /var/lib/dpkg/arch file needed for Rasp PI Stretch Lite?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is supposed to be fixed in dpkg 1.20.6, as part of https://bugs.debian.org/969472.

Comment: Thank you; I ended up patching the code with the above change because I could not wait, nor could upgrade 1000's of devices already deployed, some without internet access.